# express socket.io Port 3000 is already in use

Tags: express, react-native, socket.io, nodemon

I would like to make real-time chat app on React-Native,

I have backend express

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90d3Y.png)

Now , I want to use socket.io in express backend , But not in app.js I would like to use socket.io in socketmessage.js , because I have more api this file

But return to me this error ; Port 3000 is already in use

How can i fix this problem?

I use this code for socket.io in socketmessage.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var router = express.Router();
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var websocket = socketio(server);
server.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on *:3000'));

// The event will be called when a client is connected.
websocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A client just joined on', socket.id);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem ? If you can't start the application on port 3000 - try `npm stop` and then `npm start` because sometimes when you stop the app, it won't stop the server until npm stop. On the other hand if you want to use port 3000 for something else - just don't use it for your nodejs server. Use different port instead.

Comment: I start nodemon www start

Answer (score 1):

Port 3000 on your machine might be already in use by other process. Follow below commands to free up the port.

```
lsof -i :3000
```

Above command lists down the process, using PID from the result execute following command:

```
kill -9 PID
```

Now restart your application.

On windows

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "3000"

Taskkill /PID <PIDNumber> /F
```

Comment: express using 3000 port , because api run on express , I would like to add socket.io in express https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073471/express-js-add-socket-io-in-routes-socketmessage-js

Comment: Can you paste your app.js too?

Comment: can you check this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161657/express-socket-io-get-socket-io-eio-3transport-pollingt-mmzadrr-404

Comment: If you want to make it modular, you can initiate express runnable process (i.e. app) in app.js and pass it to your socketmessage.js

Comment: i tried this and 3000 port using by express , if I kill it express js stoped , but my code run in express js

Comment: Please refer to this https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express. I hope you're not using the same port twice.

Comment: Thanks for everythink @Ashish :)
I solved my problem thanks to https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1556#issuecomment-48119015

Answer (score 0):

For windows:

**Step 1**: In command-line, type the following command:

netstat -ano | findstr yourPortNumber

This will give PID which is the process identifier

**Step 2**: Kill the task by typing the following command:

taskkill/PID yourPIDNumber

**Step 3**: If the second step does not work, append /F to the second command as follows:

taskkill/PID yourPIDNumber /F